# Loop to split string by delimiter not respecting all deliminators

Tags: c++, string, delimiter

I'm splitting an `std::string` into words and append each to a doubly linked list. I've written an `append_word` method to add to the list, which I've verified is not the issue (adding words individually through this method is perfectly fine). My function is as follows:

```
int set_text(std::string text) {
    u_int i, word_start, word_end;
    i = word_start = word_end = 0;

    while (i <= text.length()) {
        if (text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '\0') {
            word_end = i;

            std::string substr = text.substr(word_start, word_end);
            // empty string argument to append_word has no effect
            if (append_word("", substr) < 0)
                return -1;
            i = word_start = ++word_end;
        } else {
            i++
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, calling this on "Lorem ipsum dolor" results in a first word of "Lorem", and a second word of "ipsum dolor" before a third word of "dolor". Why is the second space only treated as a delimiter in the third word but not the second?

Comment: Would you be open to using [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to split, or do you want to preserve this function's approach?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr takes arguments of `pos` and `npos`, i.e. starting position and length of the substring. It does not take starting position and ending position. You're treating it as the latter.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, one line at a time, what observations did you make? This is what a debugger is for, so doesn't it make a lot of sense for you to spend a few minutes learning how to use one, so you can easily see exactly what your program is doing so you can fix it yourself instead of asking others for help?

Comment: This should be closed as a typo? Or is there a better category?

Comment: @JohnFilleau I should read documentation. Thanks